# How to fix: apache2 CAPTCHA generates a background graphics, but no characters?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, fonts

Characters are missing on the 'CAPTCHA' image, yet the background graphics looks fine.

No errors are displayed - the image works itself.

Used fonts are various, put in CAPTCHA's folder as `.TTF` files (maybe the problem is file type?).

Works on external servers, not on my localhost though. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS apache2).

How to fix or diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the font path** from `font.ttf` to `./font.ttf`, so add the `./` part before the actual path.

Thanks to [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-905187.html).

Comment: Isn't that a bug? Works fine without the `./`  part on another servers... Config maybe?